# Diameter of random graph.

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Basically I was given a random graph with fixed probability and I need to prove that the diameter of the random graph is asymptotically 2.  See the following picture for the detail of the question. a.a.s here means asymptotically almost sure. [image]

My attempt is to find the expected value of the shortest path between any pair of vertices. Let $X$ be the random variable indicating the length of the shortest path between any pair of vertices. Then $Pr(X=1) = p$, $Pr(X=2) = (n-2)p^2(1-p)$, $Pr(X=3) = (n-2)(n-3)p^3[1-Pr(X=1)-Pr(X=2)]$ and etc. But to the best of my knowledge, it seems not easy to calculate the expected value based these probabilities asymptotically. Any suggestions on how should I calculate the expectation or should I try another direction?

**EDIT1:** I think I was very wrong about the probability. $Pr(X=2)$ goes to infinity according to my calculation. Sorry about the naive mistake. I am trying Martigale.

**Edit2:** Maybe think of it from eccentricity.

**Edit3:** Let $X$ be the eccentricity of vertex $v$. $Pr(X=1) = p^{n-1}$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. $Pr(X>2)$ indicates that there is a vertex $u$ such that $u$ is not connected to $v$ or any of the vertices that is directly connected to $v$. So $Pr(X>2) = (n-1)(1-p)^{(|S|+1)}$, where $S$ is the set of vertices connected to $v$. Since $|S| = np + o(1)$ when n is sufficiently large, $Pr(X>2)$ also goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. I think it is probably the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution you suggest in your third edit isn't rigorous, since $\left|S\right|=(n-2)p$ is just an approximation; the actual number of edges emanating from $v$ varies. (It's also not clear how "given $v$ and $u$" is to be interpreted, given that $u$ was introduced in an existential clause referring to the vertices being counted.)

The probability that a given pair of vertices is not connected by a path of length $2$ is $(1-p^2)^{n-2}$, since all edges forming these potential paths are distinct. Thus the expected number of pairs not thus connected is $\binom n2(1-p^2)^{n-2}$, which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ at fixed $p\gt0$. The probability for the diameter to exceed $2$ is less than this expected number, and thus also goes to $0$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an extra factor $1-p$ to ensure the pair of vertices is not already adjacent?

Comment: @user76284: No. The probability that the vertices aren't connected by a path of length $2$ is correct as written. If the vertices are adjacent, they're connected by a path of length $1$, not $2$. If you wanted to get the probability that they're not connected by a path of length *at most* $2$, you'd have to consider the case of a path of length $1$. However, that would be more complicated than just multiplying by a factor; you'd have to do inclusion-exclusion. This complication is unnecessary, since we only need an upper bound on the probability, so it's enough to consider paths of length $2$.